# Jupyter notebook new cell type default

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I use a [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org),

I would like new cells to be of type "markdown".

By default, the type of new cells is "code". Which config file should I modify and which variable should I change?

Comment: "Setting insert cell default type?" is an open issue on the jupyter git repo since 2014 https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5952

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the `site-packages` directory of your python environment and modify `site-packages/notebook/static/notebook/js/main.min.js`

Find something like

```
Notebook.options_default = {
    // can be any cell type, or the special values of
    // 'above', 'below', or 'selected' to get the value from another cell.
    default_cell_type: 'code'
};
```

change `default_cell_type: 'code'` into `default_cell_type: 'markdown'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: For me, this changes the default cell type in the toolbar to 'Markdown', but when I actually create a new cell, it quickly switches back to 'Code' and creates a code cell.

Comment: So, is there a way to change or add an "insert new cell" shortcut to insert a Markdown cell?

Comment: works great. Thanks! :) (just adding this since one comment above doubts that it works, and I nearly didn't try)

Answer (score 6):

In JupyterLab, you can go to `Settings -> Advanced Settings manager -> Notebook` and then add the following in "User Preferences":

```json
{
    "defaultCell": "markdown"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter-Lab 4 you can go to `Settings > Settings Editor`, then a tab with (all) settings opens up. Go in `Notebook` (in the sidedar) and change the "Default cell type":

[image]